# CSS Hover (header and text)

Tags: html, css

Is it possible using CSS's `hover` that when I hover over the header background the `h1` and `p` tags in the header fade and blur and if so how do I do it?

How do I tell my header to blur the text?

## My CSS thus far:

#### header:

```
.header:hover {
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888;
  max-height: 420px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 3.2s ease;
  transition: all 3.2s ease;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px);
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the `:hover` selector to an element earlier in the chain, such as:

```
.header:hover p {
    /* blur filters, etc. */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px);
}
```

This will apply the specified properties to paragraphs within the `.header` div while the `.header` div is hovered. You should be able to do something similar for the `h1`

Comment: Another Question: Is there any way to smooth the transition from blur to non blurred when the mouse leaves without using js? at the moment it snaps from blurred to non blurred

Comment: @Exhausted Yes, you'll need to apply your `transition` properties to the base element rather than the `:hover` state of it, otherwise it will only have those transitions while hovered. Here's a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XEwWs/1/